# store abstract member, keep interface simple

Tags: c++, abstract-class, shared-ptr

I know that it is *not* possible to have an instance of an abstract class as a base member of another class, i.e.,

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {
  public:
    Base() {};
    virtual ~Base() {};
    virtual int yield() = 0;
};

class C1: public Base {
  public:
    C1(): Base() {};
    virtual ~C1() {};
    virtual int yield() {return 1;};
};

class D {
  public:
    D(Base & b): b_(b) {};
    virtual ~D() {};
  private:
    Base b_;
}

int main() {
  C1 c;
  D d(c);
}
```

will fail to compile with the error

```
test.cpp:22:10: error: cannot declare field ‘D::b_’ to be of abstract type ‘Base’
```

The obvious workaround is to use (shared) pointers instead. This, however, makes `main` somewhat more complicated to read,

```cpp
int main() {
  auto c = std::make_shared<C1>();
  D d(c);
}
```

which I would really like to avoid.

Is there a way to keep the `main` file as simple as in the above example and still achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: TL;DR; There's no such thing like an _instance of an abstract class/struct_! Use a pointer or reference instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. When you are creating `D` it allocates (in heap or in stack) memory for `B`. And `C1` class needs size of base class `B` plus size of extra variables/etc in `C1` itself even if there are nothing new.

So, use pointers instead.

Answer (score 0):

The error caused by `virtual int yield() = 0;`. If you use `virtual int yield()`, it will works. When you used `virtual int yield() = 0;`, it said that the function is a `pure virtual` function, so you must `override` it. So you should give its `inheritance class` and use `the instance of inheritance class` in `class C1`. In a world, `virtual int yield() = 0;` only remind you that it is only a interface, you must override it. I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Since Base is an [abstract class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Classes/Abstract_Classes) (has at least one pure virtual function), it can't be instantiated directly.
When you declare D's class member as "Base b_", you are effectively trying to create an instance. You can instead use a pointer there (or some kind of safe/smart pointer).

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {
  public:
    Base() {};
    virtual ~Base() {};
    virtual int yield() = 0;
};

class C1: public Base {
  public:
    C1(): Base() {};
    virtual ~C1() {};
    virtual int yield() {return 1;};
};

class D {
  public:
    D(Base * b): b_(b) {};
    virtual ~D() {};
  private:
    Base *b_;  // Use a pointer or safe ptr or something of that sort.
}

int main() {
  C1 c;
  D d(&c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No.    One of the properties of an abstract class is that it cannot be instantiated.   That means an instance of an abstract class cannot be a member of another class.

Even if `Base` was not abstract, your class `D`'s constructor would be slicing the object passed.   If passed an instance of `C1`, the copying (in the initialiser list of `D`'s constructor) would not magically cause an instance of `D` to contain an object of type `C`.   It would instead create a copy only of the `Base` part of that object.

In short, your design is broken, and will not work even if - syntactically - it would be possible to simplify the code in `main()`.